# LG treasure: phone performance issues

Tags: lg

My phone (1 month old) suddenly takes forever, if at all to browse internet. I haven't downloaded anything and scanned for virus, but nothing shows up. Honestly starting to think LG is scamming the public into buying new phones every month. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is ridiculous, no mobile company wants your to buy a mobile every month.
I assume your phone is *LG treasure L51AL*

Your phone stats are

> Qualcomm® Snapdragon™ 1.1 GHz Quad-Core MSM8909;
>
> Internal Memory: 8 GB (up to 2.87 GB usable)
>
> I was unable to find your Mobile's RAM; please provide that

1. Shut down your phone and restart.
2. Do you close your applications after use or do you minimize them?
3. Download "clean master" and clean your mobile; it gets rid of unnecessary caches and other stuff.
4. Are you sure that there aren't any third party app which has come with the phone?

You processor isn't very good; its 1.1GHz and Quad-Core; so your phone would be relatively not fast. Your storage space is also very little; make sure it isn't almost full, as that could cause your mobile's performance to decrease.